# ISS business venture cost?

Tags: iss, cost, commercial, equipment

How much would it cost for a business to place some self-maintaining electronic equipment aboard the ISS? Would it be a monthly fee, or a one-time transportation and installation fee? Would that business be responsible for supplying electricity for the equipment, or will the ISS be able to support the electric power needs for such equipment?
If this question cannot be answered here, who can I contact that can answer these questions for me?

I'm sorry that I cannot disclose the type of electronic equipment that I'm referring to, this is a business venture that I have to keep under the radar of other businesses, until the equipment is in place, or other businesses will be trying to do this first.

Comment: [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/astro-pi-mission-update-1/) might give you an idea of the many certification hurdles involved in the process. If you follow that project, they have given easily understandable explanations about power, cooling, safety etc. To get this going as a business venture, a commercial company would have to present an **outstanding** case.

Comment: Shoot these folks an unsolicited proposal http://www.iss-casis.org/Opportunities/UnsolicitedProposals.aspx

Answer (score 3):

NASA tends to do such things as joint partnerships. An excellent example was the [Bigelow BEAM module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigelow_Expandable_Activity_Module). NASA actually paid Bigelow to test their hardware on orbit. However, while Bigelow holds many patents on such technology, they are required to provide data to NASA.

In fact, NASA has many such partnerships set up with companies such as SpaceX and Blue Origins, where the commercial partner pays for the cost of things, NASA provides expertise, and the commercial partner provides data in return.

In your case, you probably want to actually launch a dedicated satellite mission to test out the hardware. There are virtually no items that can't be tested on the ground or on a stand alone satellite first. Depending on the size of your payload, it could cost $60 million to launch, or more.

If you really want to have a commercial venture with a space station, you're best bet is to wait for the [Bigelow 330](https://bigelowaerospace.com/b330/), which is set to launch in 4-5 years. They don't have the rates for what you are asking for available online, but I'm sure if you talk with them you can get a quote for what it would take. Of course, NDAs can be signed both ways.

In fact, NASA is [looking to put something](http://spacenews.com/nasa-seeking-ideas-for-use-of-space-station-docking-port/) where the Bigelow BEAM module is.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like I have a lot of work ahead of me! Wish I could have given you more details, but I'm sure that this could be something that NASA would like to partner with me.